# Como otimizar o tempo de carregamento de um projeto Ionic2?

Tags: apache-cordova, angular, ionic2

Fiz um aplicativo com Ionic2 do zero, utilizando como padrão o projeto "blank" seguindo a documentação.

O projeto em si está funcionando sem problemas.

Porém uma coisa que me intriga um pouco é o tempo de carregamento na inicialização do aplicativo.

Embora eu esteja mostrando um Splashscreen enquanto o carregamento do cordova é realizado, está levando em média 10 segundos(em algumas simulações chegou a 15 Segundos) para terminar o carregamento.

Depois de terminar o carregamento eu fecho o SplashScreen no evento disparado:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {

  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();

});
```

O meu config.xml está com o splashscreen habilitado, porém se eu tirar o splash, o aplicativo fica em tela branca(pois não terminou de carregar ainda).

Config.xml

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~2.0.2" />
```

Console do tempo de carregamento

```
Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 9833 ms 
Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 10285 ms
```

Baseado nisso, tenho os seguintes questionamentos:

> Há alguma forma de diminuir o tempo de carregamento?
>
> Há alguma configuração/configurações que permitam que o aplicativo inicie direto, sem esse carregamento prévio?
>
> Se o tempo for necessário, há alguma forma de iniciar parte da aplicação e deixar o carregamento ocorrer em segundo plano?

Comment: Muito ampla! Pode ter `N` motivos. Dá uma olhada sobre [`lazy loading`](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1) na `v3`

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade minha dúvida seria com o aplicativo base do ionic por exemplo, em qualquer uma das opções de app padrão(blank, tabs, sidemenu) ionic, esse problema já ocorre, por que demora tanto a inicialização?

Comment: Isso ocorre com qualquer projeto novo seu? Caso sim, reinstale os npm packages do ionic/cordova e atualize-os.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade já fiz isso, fiz inclusive hoje e o tempo de carregamento inicial de um projeto blank ou sidemenu(os que testei) continuam superiores a 9 segundos.

Comment: O meu inicia em 1482 ms e olha que já instalei mais de 10 plugins. De uma olhada nesse link https://blog.khophi.co/optimize-ionic-2-app-production/ . Colocar o enableProdMode(); e a flag --prod faz muita diferença. Da uma lida